# End of file in readline

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get an Perl program working. I get an error

```
readline() on closed filehandle IN at Test.pl line 368, <IN> line 65.
```

Lines 363-369 of the program looks like this

```
print "Primer3 is done! \n";
my $forward = "$snpid.for";
my @forward_out;
my $i=0;
open(IN,$forward);
while(<IN>){
    chomp;s/\r//;
```

And refers to the configuration file. The last line (line 65) looks like this

```
num_cpus = 40
```

So the configuration file is not correct, or Perl does not recognize that this is the end of the file.

Is there a way to solve this?

#### Update

Based on the comments I added the `open() or die` command and got this:

> No such file or directory at Test.pl line 367.

The `open` command is part of a subroutine `Primer3_Run`

```
sub Primer3_Run {    
    my $snpid = shift;  
    my $seq   = shift;  

    my $tmp_input = "Primer3.tmp.input";    
    my $len       = length($seq);    

    open(OUT, ">$tmp_input");
    
    close OUT; 
    
    if ( -e "$snpid.for" ) { 
        system "del
        $snpid.for";
    } 

    if ( -e "$snpid.rev" ) { 
        system "del $snpid.rev";
    } 
    
    system
        "$params{'primer3'}     
        Primer3.tmp.input 
        Primer3.Log.txt 2>&1 "; 
    
    my $forward = "$snpid.for"; 
    
    my @forward_out;
    my $i = 0; 
    
    open(IN, $forward) or die $!;
```

Comment: As the error message clearly says, there is no open file on the `IN` file handle. Showing the contents of the file and how you have tried to read it doesn't help at all. Please help us with a less restricted view of your code.

Comment: The filehandle (`IN`) isn't open when you try to read from it. So either you never opened it successfully or you have accidentally closed it before reaching this line. It would help tremendously to see the line that opens the filehandle (it will start `open IN ...`). My guess would be that you don't open the file successfully (perhaps because the file isn't in the right place) and you don't check the return code from the call to `open()`.

Comment: Are there any calls to `close()` in your code? Particularly inside the `while` loop.

Comment: @Dave: The file handle has been opened correctly at some point to have reached `<IN> line 65`!

Comment: Thank you for the input.
The lines before open() looks like this:
 >print "Primer3 is done! \n";
 >my $forward = "$snpid.for";
 >my @forward_out;
 >my $i=0;
 >open(IN,$forward);
 >while(<IN>){
  >chomp;s/\r//;

Comment: Please *edit* your question to include additional code or data. It is unreadable within comments.

Comment: Please change `open(IN, $forward)` to `open(IN, $forward) or die $!` and report the result.

Comment: Please show the rest of the `while` block

Comment: Is the `open(IN, $forward)` itself inside a loop? Do you open multiple `$forward` files?

Comment: My guess is that `$snpid` takes multiple values and you don't handle the case where it becomes undefined. Do you have `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` in place at the top of the program as they should be?

Comment: One more debugging change to your `open()` call. Can you change it to `open(IN,$forward) or die "$forward: $!";`

Comment: @TwanK: And please, if you want people to read and understand your code, take the time to format it properly. What are all those `>` signs at the start of each line? And you only seem to have shown us half of the subroutine.

Comment: Why have you stopped responding? Please remember that ***the primary purpose of a*** **Stack Overflow** ***page is to inform others who arrive here through a search***. This is not all just for you, and if you have discovered a solution then it is incumbent on you to describe and explain it, probably by writing an answer to your own question. Please be responsible and give at least as much help as you have received.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've revealed, the problem will be this block

```
if ( -e "$snpid.for" ) { system "del $snpid.for"; }
```

followed soon afterwards by this

```
my $forward = "$snpid.for"; 

open(IN, $forward) or die $!;
```

The new `or die $!` is presumably from my advice, so previously you were deleting `"$snpid.for"` and then trying to open it for input. The error you saw should be expected

> No such file or directory at Test.pl line 367.

You just deleted it!

All I can think of that may help is to be more organised with your coding. What did you mean when you tried to open a file that you had just made sure didn't exist?

Beyond that, you *must always* add `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of *every* Perl program you write. Use *lexical file handles* together with the *three-parameter* form of `open` and *always check* the status of *every* `open` call, using `die` including the value of `$!` in the die string to explain why the `open` failed.

Comment: Thank you all for your input and suggestions. (It is my first time doing something in perl and got the script through someone else).

I removed the if-commands which include a system del command, thus making sure everything will not be removed. But, the error message still is there.